# bash скрипт. В автоматическом режиме через cron выполняется не полностью

Tags: bash, curl, резервное-копирование

Добрый день.
Есть скрипт для резервного копирования баз данных MySQL и заливки на яндекс-диск:

```
#/usr/bin/bash
# шифрование файла
GPG_COMMAND="gpg -c -z 0 --no-batch --passphrase 123"

MYSQL_FILE=database_backup_`date +%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S`.sql.gz.gpg

# бэкап бд
mysqldump -u root -padmin --events --ignore-table=mysql.event -h 127.0.0.1 --all-databases | gzip | $GPG_COMMAND> /var/www/mysql_backups/$MYSQL_FILE

# если бэкап не создался
if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne "0" ]
then
    echo ERROR MYSQL DUMP
    # отправить смс
    curl -d "text=Error backup all-databases." http://sms.ru/sms/send\?api_id=11111-5A6D-34545-CE5E-111\&to=380631111111
    # отправить эл. письмо
    echo "Error backup all-databases." | mail -s "Error mysql dump" example@example.ru
    exit 1
else
    echo GOOD MYSQL DUMP
    # отправить с помощью curl на яндекс диск и записать статус в RESPONSE_STATUS
    RESPONSE_STATUS=$(curl --user login:password -T /var/www/mysql_backups/$MYSQL_FILE https://webdav.yandex.ru/backup_ubuntu_mysql/ -sw '%{http_code}' -m 100) 

    # если вернулся статус 201, значит закачалось удачно
    if [ $RESPONSE_STATUS == 201 ]
    then
        echo GOOD PUSH YANDEX
        echo GOOD BACKUP
        # удаляем бэкап из локальной папки
        unlink /var/www/mysql_backups/$MYSQL_FILE
        exit 0  
    # если не закачалось, отправляем смс и эл. письмо
    else
        echo BAD PUSH YANDEX        
        curl -d "text=Error upload backup to Yandex Disk. Response Status Code != 201." http://sms.ru/sms/send\?api_id=111-444-8059-CE5E-5DSFDS8A8\&to=380631111111
        echo "Response Status Code != 201." | mail -s "Error upload backup all-databases to Yandex Disk" example@example.ru
        exit 1
    fi   
fi
```

Если запускаю в Ubuntu 14.04 через терминал `./all_database.sh`, скрипт отрабатывает удачно, т.е. создается бэкап и заливается на яндекс диск:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если добавляю задание в crontab:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То скрипт отрабатывает не полностью. Т. е. создаётся дамп бд и всё. На яндекс-диск файл не заливается. И посмотреть в каких-то логах, например, я не могу, в и чем возникла загвоздка. Дал файлу права `chmod 777`, но всё равно полностью не отрабатывает, хотя если проблема была бы в правах, тогда дамп бд не создался бы.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ну так на вскидку, от имени какого пользователя запускается в кроне скрипт? От root, у вас, от имен  пользователя локального. Вот тут и ищите. Вообще по шагам можно echo напихать в качестве отладки, и посмотреть что на почту придет

Comment: Добавьте `echo $RESPONSE_STATUS` и посмотрите что вернёт.

Comment: Вы свой uid от смс ру спрячьте ;)

Answer (score 2):

Добавил в кронтабе(crontab -e) перед путем ко скрипту фразу bash, и теперь скрипт выполняется полностью в автоматическом режиме. Всем спасибо)
Пример ниже:

```
01 00 * * * bash /home/andrey/backup_scripts/all_database.sh
```

Comment: Как альтернативу - измените первую строку на `#!/usr/bin/bash` (сейчас у вас без восклицательного знака). Если у вас bash действительно в /usr/bin, а не /bin.